# Problem with keyBy in lodash. Lodash removed some properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have an array for example

```
let arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:2, c:3}, {a:2, c:3} ];
```

and I used the keyBy function

```
const f = _.keyBy(arr, e => e.a);
```

Result is

```
1: {a: 1, b: 2}
2: {a: 2, c: 3}
```

But I need all properties, the result I expected is

```
1: {a: 1, b: 2, c:3}
2: {a: 2, c: 3}
```

What I have to do?

Comment: `_.keyBy` takes the last element with the key. Which element do you want? Do you want the element with the most properties? Or do you want to merge all elements with the same key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the items by `a`, and the use `_.mapValues()` to iterate the group, and merge each group to a single object:

```js
const arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:2, c:3}, {a:2, c:3} ];

const result = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(arr, 'a'),
  group => _.merge({}, ...group)
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can create a terser function using the same idea:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues, mergeAll } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy('a'),
  mapValues(mergeAll),
)

const arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:2, c:3}, {a:2, c:3} ];

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```